# Moving an image from the top of the navbar to the navbar when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

Just as I explained in the title, I want to move image to a `sticky-top` bootstrap navbar when scrolling. I have a mock-up code down here:

```css
.mainlogo{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 50%;
}

/* header */

.navbar{
   
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #0D4671;
}
.img{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

<div class="container">
    <div class="mainlogo">
        <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1098662/pexels-photo-1098662.jpeg"  alt="" class=" w-100">
    </div>
</div>

<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/1098662/pexels-photo-1098662.jpeg" alt="" width="30" height="30" class="logo">
            A Car
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
            </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <h1>Loremlorem</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui atque magni consectetur! Modi, quia inventore, voluptates eligendi at ipsum commodi perferendis neque, incidunt fugit cupiditate labore molestiae omnis nihil? Voluptatibus.</p>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a car image at the top of navbar. All I want to do is when I scroll down and when navbar sticks top, image moves to the the navbar brand location.

So is there a way to do this? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may achieve this using a bit of javascript.
Just check whenever navbar `offsetTop` is 0 and then move the image.
You may do this using `scroll` event or even better for performance - with `Intersection Observer`

Anyway if image will be the same I don`t see why you would want to move it ? This will take repaint, reflow of your page which is not optimal for performance. If both images are the same - the request for them will be cached and you wouldn`t have 2 same request, so nothing to worry about from that point of view.

Comment: I tried using that but my mind is melting right now. I mean i get that i can move image but cant figure out how to move it into the navbar and stick it there.

And yes I know its not optimal but sadly this is not my desicion.

Comment: On what exactly you are stuck ? 
You may get the whole image and change its place on DOM or just have <img> with empty `src` in navbar and whenever it needs - go and copy/paste source from first image